# Base 64 encoded image send in email ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, mime-types

Is there any work round / alternative to sending image in email.
I am generated base64 string from image and setting src to it . 
This successfully shows image on browser but to my horror base 64 Data URi method is not supported by most of email clients .

```
// value below is MemoryStream object holding image
string ImgUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(value.ToArray(), 0,    
                 value.ToArray().Length);"
```

I have put lot of effort in my code . Please guide me how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 encoded embedded images are not supported by most of email clients.
Alternative is to use `LinkedResources` and attach to mail body.

Answer (score 3):

Add the image as an attachment to the message and set it's ContentId and ContentDisposition:

```
var attachment = new Attachment(path);
msg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
attachment.ContentId = "myimage";
attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
```

Then you can refer to the image from your HTML:

```
<img src="cid:myimage" />
```

Comment: what is the `msg` variable here

Comment: msg is your System.Net.Mail.MailMessage instance for the message you are sending.